# r not reading the first row of csv file

Tags: r

I am trying to read a bi csv file with this simple command:

```
k<-read.csv("/home/babak/BB/Data.csv")[,1:10]
```

If I am showing the `k`. I see this output

```
2      523  587  575  394  444  491  471  448  555  587
3      539  602  588  399  443  479  483  466  554  571
4      531  608  592  391  467  486  475  468  555  576
5      540  582  582  403  452  467  459  454  542  587
6      539  599  575  398  467  492  463  471  573  579
7      529  591  582  395  456  491  472  455  543  579
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

here I don't see the first row, and the result begins from the second row. would you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the argument `header = FALSE`:

```
read.csv("/home/babak/BB/Data.csv", header = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
k <- read.csv("/home/babak/BB/Data.csv", header = FALSE)[,1:10]
```